Reducing the length of long expressions inserted in Message
It looks like WRI is quietly changing the truncation of long expressions inserted in Message between versions.
For example, version 14.0 gives
ff::foo = "Some text `1` another text `2` final text";
Message[ff::foo, Range[1000], Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 15}]]


while in version 14.1 one gets

I am aware of $MessagePrePrint, Shallow, Short etc. My question is how and from where to extract the default settings that would allow customization to the previous version settings.

If I understand the situation correctly, I would say they fixed a bug in Shallow. The third usage case of Shallow is:

Shallow[expr, {depth, length}] also gives parts whose lengths are above the specified limit in skeleton form.

However, up to version 14.0, it seems that length was not taken into account, and it was always set to its default (ie. length = 10). Inside message formatting functions, Shallow is called as Shallow[expr, {10, 50}].
Let's see the difference in the two versions:
(* Version 14.0 *)
Shallow[Range[100], {10, 50}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, <<90>>} *)

(* Version 14.1 *)
Shallow[Range[100], {10, 50}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
    37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, <<50>>} *)


That sounds as a plausible explanation.  My experiments with Shallow in version 14.0 also raised my suspicion that something is wrong with the Shallow optional arguments. I haven't repeated in version 14.1, however.
